# Tornado, Nginx, Apache ab - apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)

Tags: python, nginx, amazon-ec2, tornado, load-testing

I am running nginx, and tornado on a c1.medium instances.

When I run ab the below is my output. Nginx will not work.  I have tried to tweak the config file for ninx to no avail.  If I run on just one port by passing nginx e.g. `

```
  http://127.0.0.1:8050/pixel?tt=ff`
```

then its fast.  See the very bottom.  This must be an nginx issue so how to I resolve?  Also below is the conf file for nginx.

```
root@ip-10-130-167-230:/etc/service# ab -n 10000 -c 50 http://127.0.0.1/pixel?tt=ff
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
Total of 9100 requests completed
```

This should smoke but yet it does not.

I set the following parmamerts

```
ulimit is at 100000

# General gigabit tuning:
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
# this gives the kernel more memory for tcp
# which you need with many (100k+) open socket connections
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 50576   64768   98152
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 2500
```

Here is my nginx conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;  # 2*number of cpus
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 32768;
events {
         worker_connections  30000;
         multi_accept on;
         use epoll;
}

http {
        upstream frontends {
          server 127.0.0.1:8050;
          server 127.0.0.1:8051;
        }
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        # Only retry if there was a communication error, not a timeout
    # on the Tornado server (to avoid propagating "queries of death"
    # to all frontends)
    proxy_next_upstream error;

        server {
        listen   80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
                ##For tornado
                location / {
                    proxy_pass_header Server;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
                    proxy_pass http://frontends;
                }
```

if I run ab by by passing nginx:

```
ab -n 100000 -c 1000 http://127.0.0.1:8050/pixel?tt=ff



root@ip-10-130-167-230:/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbTornadoServer# ab -n 100000 -c 1000 http://127.0.0.1:8050/pixel?tt=ff
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 10000 requests
Completed 20000 requests
Completed 30000 requests
Completed 40000 requests
Completed 50000 requests
Completed 60000 requests
Completed 70000 requests
Completed 80000 requests
Completed 90000 requests
Completed 100000 requests
Finished 100000 requests


Server Software:        TornadoServer/2.2.1
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8050

Document Path:          /pixel?tt=ff
Document Length:        42 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   52.436 seconds
Complete requests:      100000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      31200000 bytes
HTML transferred:       4200000 bytes
Requests per second:    1907.08 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       524.363 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.524 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          581.06 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0  411 1821.7      0   21104
Processing:    23   78 121.2     65    5368
Waiting:       22   78 121.2     65    5368
Total:         53  489 1845.0     65   23230

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     65
  66%     69
  75%     78
  80%     86
  90%    137
  95%   3078
  98%   3327
  99%   9094
 100%  23230 (longest request)


2012/05/16 20:48:32 [error] 25111#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8051/", host: "127.0.0.1"
2012/05/16 20:48:32 [error] 25111#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8050/", host: "127.0.0.1"
2012/05/16 20:53:48 [error] 28905#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8051/", host: "127.0.0.1"
2012/05/16 20:53:48 [error] 28905#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8050/", host: "127.0.0.1"
2012/05/16 20:55:35 [error] 30180#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8051/", host: "127.0.0.1"
2012/05/16 20:55:35 [error] 30180#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8050/", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Oupput when using the -v 10 option on ab:

```
GIF89a
LOG: Response code = 200
LOG: header received:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 16 May 2012 21:56:50 GMT
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Length: 42
Connection: close
Etag: "d5fceb6532643d0d84ffe09c40c481ecdf59e15a"
Server: TornadoServer/2.2.1
Set-Cookie: rtbhui=867bccde-2bc0-4518-b422-8673e07e19f6; Domain=rtb.rtbhui.com; expires=Fri, 16 May 2014 21:56:50 GMT; Path=/
```

Comment: I found my issue...sadly..haha...my chef run was restarting supervised every chef run at 30 seconds.  i had a bug there.  Fixed then then issues resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using apache benchmark on a sinatra app using webrick. I found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/323840/apache-bench-test-erroron-os-x-apr-socket-recv-connection-reset-by-peer-54) .

Its actually problem of your Apache server.

The bug has been removed in the higher versions of apache. Try downloading them [here](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and looking for information in the logs i got this lines:

```
Oct 15 10:41:30 bal1 kernel: [1031008.706185] nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.
Oct 15 10:41:31 bal1 kernel: [1031009.757069] nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.
Oct 15 10:41:32 bal1 kernel: [1031009.939489] nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.
Oct 15 10:41:32 bal1 kernel: [1031010.255115] nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.
```

In my particular case, the conntrack module is use inside iptables because the same server have the firewall.

One solution for fix that is unloading the conntrack module, and other and easy is with this two lines applied in the firewall policy:

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p tcp  -j NOTRACK
iptables -t raw -I OUTPUT -p tcp  -j NOTRACK
```